# ExpansionTile in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, expandablelistview

I am trying to build an expansion tile from the data I get from backend and the data from backend looks like

```
var sampleresponse = [ 
   {"Total Income": 500.0},
   {"Total Expense": 1000.0},
   {"Maintenance": 500.0},
   {"Tank Water": 100.0, "truck Charges": 900.0},
];

var sampletotalIncome = sampleresponse[0];
var sampletotalExpense = sampleresponse[1];
var sampledetailIncome = sampleresponse[2];
var sampledetailExpense = sampleresponse[3];

var sampletotalIncomeKeys = sampletotalIncome.keys;
var sampletotalExpenseKeys = sampletotalExpense.keys;
var sampledetailIncomeKeys = sampledetailIncome.Keys;
var sampledetailExpenseKeys = sampledetailExpense.keys;

var sampletotalIncomevalue = sampletotalIncome.value;
var sampletotalExpensevalue = sampletotalExpense.value;
var sampledetailIncomevalue = sampledetailIncome.value;
var sampledetailExpensevalue= sampledetailExpense.value;

//sampletotalIncomeKeys is [Total Income] 
//sampletotalIncomevalue is [500.0] 
//sampletotalExpenseKeys is [Total Expense] 
//sampletotalExpensevalue is [1000.0] 
//sampledetailIncomeKeys is [Maintanence] 
//sampledetailIncomevalue is [500.0] 
//sampledetailExpenseKeys is [Tank Water, truck Charges] 
//sampledetailedExpensevalue is [100.0, 900.0]
```

where "Maintenance":500.0 should be placed under "Total Income" and the "Total Expense" should contain the "Tank Water" and "truck Charges". Here is my code:

Snippet from ExpansionTile.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
final MyTile myTile;

StuffInTiles(this.myTile);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return _buildTiles(myTile);
}

Widget _buildTiles(MyTile t) {
  if (t.children.isEmpty)
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(
        t.title,
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      trailing: new Text(
        t.value,
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  return new ExpansionTile(
    key: new PageStorageKey<MyTile>(t),
    title: new Text(
      t.title,
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    trailing: new Text(
      t.value,
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    children: t.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
  );
}
```

}

```
class MyTile {
 final String title;
 final String value;
 final List<MyTile> children;

 MyTile(this.title, this.value, [this.children = const <MyTile>[]]);

}
```

}

Snippet from Main.dart:

```
List<MyTile> itemList = <MyTile>[

          new MyTile(
            sampletotalIncomeKeys.toString(),
            sampletotalIncomevalue.toString(),
            sampledetailIncomeKeys
                .map(
                  (items) => new 
            MyTile(sampledetailIncomeKeys.toString(),
                      sampledetailIncomevalue.toString()),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
          new MyTile(
            sampletotalExpenseKeys.toString(),
            sampletotalExpensevalue.toString(),
            sampledetailedExpense.map((items, value) => 
            MyTile(items.toString(), value.toString()).toString(),
              ).toString()

          ),
        ];

 ...........
new Expanded(
   child: new ListView.builder(
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return new StuffInTiles(itemList[index]);
     },
   itemCount: itemList.length,
  ),
```

)

With this I am getting an error as

"The argument type "String" cannot be assigned to parameter type List. I am not understanding this. Can some please help me with the logic for this?

Thank you!

Comment: which line do you have the error?

Comment: new MyTile(
            sampletotalExpenseKeys.toString(),
            sampletotalExpensevalue.toString(),
            sampledetailedExpense.map((items, value) => 
            MyTile(items.toString(), value.toString()).toString(),
              ).toString()

Comment: Update your question with the values of sampletotalexpensesvalue... Etc

Comment: Your MyTile is not correct i think, you are containing  a list of your children in your children, it doesn't look right. You must keep the list outside of your MyTile

Comment: @diegoveloper, updated the question with the info

Comment: @warlock, Thats the implementation, the children of MyTile inside the parent MyTile will make the children to expand when the parent MyTile is tapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong on this part:

```
    List<MyTile> itemList = <MyTile>[

              new MyTile(
                sampletotalIncomeKeys.toString(),
                sampletotalIncomevalue.toString(),
                sampledetailIncomeKeys
                    .map(
                      (items) => new 
                MyTile(sampledetailIncomeKeys.toString(),
                          sampledetailIncomevalue.toString()),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
              new MyTile(
                sampletotalExpenseKeys.toString(),
                sampletotalExpensevalue.toString(),
                sampledetailedExpense.map((items, value) => 
                MyTile(items.toString(), value.toString()).toString(),
                  ).toString()

              ),
            ];
```

The last parameter of your second object is wrong, it should be a `List` not a `String`, replace by this code:

```
          List<MyTile> itemList = <MyTile>[
            new MyTile(
              sampletotalIncomeKeys.toString(),
              sampletotalIncomevalue.toString(),
              sampledetailIncomeKeys
                  .map(
                    (items) => new MyTile(sampledetailIncomeKeys.toString(),
                        sampledetailIncomevalue.toString()),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
            new MyTile(
            sampletotalExpenseKeys.toString(),
            sampletotalExpensevalue.toString(),
            sampledetailedExpense.keys
                .map(
                  (key) =>
                      MyTile(key, sampledetailedExpense[key].toString()),
                )
                .toList()),
         ];
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. But I would want to send the value too to MyTile. If the implementation was just for the name which would be in the title of Expansion tile, it works fine, but I would want another value to be displayed on the trailing part of the Expansion Tile. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: check the code, I'm sending two values:  MyTile(item.title.toString(), item.value.toString()),

Comment: Thanks @diegoveloper, But I still get the same error.

Comment: could you upload a screenshot and your code updated to check the problem?

Comment: @ArunKumar could you check again? I updated the code

Comment: I thought the same should work as per your code update, but when I try your code, I get an error called "The return type "MyTile" isn't a "Map Entry", as defined by anonymous closure".  Its at the point  "MyTile(itemString.toString(), itemDouble.toString()),"    I could not understand that. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of sampledetailedExpense?

Comment: sampletotalIncomeKeys is [Total Income]
sampletotalIncomevalue is [500.0]
sampletotalExpenseKeys is [Total Expense]
sampletotalExpensevalue is [1000.0]
sampledetailIncomeKeys is [Maintanence]
sampledetailIncomevalue is [500.0]
 sampledetailExpenseKeys is [Tank Water, truck Charges]
sampledetailedExpensevalue is [100.0, 900.0]

Comment: update your question with your code complete, I don't understand the value of your variables

Comment: what is the value of "sampledetailedExpense" ??

Comment: {"Tank Water": 100.0, "truck Charges": 900.0},